# How to plot the solution of a function while varying a parameter

Tags: numerics

I have a function of a single variable that I want to solve numerically for different values of a parameter and then plot the results.  I have a general equilibrium model that I can get to a reduced form of a single variable.  I want to see how that variable changes with the parameter and plot the results.

Comment: We need more details. Please show an example of your function, and explain what you mean by saying that you want to "solve the function numerically" (you want to find its roots?). What have you tried in *Mathematica* so far?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following?

```
f[x_, m_] := 1 + m x
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x, m], {x, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}
  ],
 {{m, 1}, -2, 2}
 ]
```

Where you can replace $f$ with your function

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Mathematica to Plot any sort of functions. Based on the amount of detail you've provided in your question it is difficult to identify what exactly you are looking for. However, here is a couple of examples with useful links to help you to get started:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Cos[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Example]

The above corresponds to Manipulate header functions in a form of

> Manipulate[expr, {u,..},{v,..},..]

You can get familiar with the notation by following this [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html#1766845292).

More advanced example can be seen below:

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  q1/Norm[{x, y} - p[[1]]] + q2/Norm[{x, y} - p[[2]]], {x, -2, 
   2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> 10], {{q1, -1}, -3, 3}, {{q2, 1}, -3, 
  3}, {{p, {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, Locator}, 
 Deployed -> True]
```

[image: Advanced example]

This code can be also viewed online on link provided above. I would encourange you to try this code out and read through documentation for function `Manipulate`.

You also might find it useful to read through this [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html).